# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python

I am working with a json file and I need to create an array with which I can work later on in my Python code.

It needs to look like this `[[1*5,1.75],[2*5,1.74],[3*5,1.76]...]` 
so i can calculate l`ike avgPoints[x][0]+avgPoints[x+1][0]`

My current code looks like this:

```
data = json.loads(json_file)

avgData = data['diameter_measurement'].split(',')
avgStep = float(data['length']) / (len(avgData) - 1)
avgPoints = list(map(lambda index, delta: [index * avgStep, 1.75 + float(delta) / 1000.0], enumerate(avgData)))
```

But when I run my code it gives me following error:

```
->TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'delta'
```

Comment: `map` passes one argument to the function you provide (depending on the number of iterables you pass to it,  but you are only passing one*. You could use `from collections import starmap` in this case, or just use a list-comprehension

Comment: Proper punishment for using `list(map(lambda ...` instead of a list comp :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over `enumerate`, you get back one item: the tuple `(index, element)`. This is not implicitly unpacked into `index, delta` when you call the `lambda`, so you have to unpack it yourself with something like `lambda index_delta: "use index_delta[0] and index_delta[1]"`. Alternatively you could define a function and unpack the function's single argument into `index` and `delta`.